# Node ECS Task Not Crashing

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ecs

Node ECS Task Not Crashing

I have an ECS worker running Node:Boron (v6.9.0).
Every now and then I get a uncaught exception.
For Example:

```
{
  "date": "Mon Jul 03 2017 09:09:29 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "process": {
  "pid": 28,
  "uid": 0,
  "gid": 0,
  "cwd": "/usr/src/app",
  "execPath": "/usr/local/bin/node",
  "version": "v6.11.0",
  "argv": [
    "/usr/local/bin/node",
    "/usr/src/app/src/poll.js"
  ],
  "memoryUsage": {
    "rss": 67502080,
    "heapTotal": 33660928,
    "heapUsed": 25145608,
    "external": 8981275
  }
},
{
  "os": {
    "loadavg": [
      0.65869140625,
      0.44921875,
      0.4541015625
    ],
    "uptime": 218908
  },
  "trace": [
    {
      "column": null,
      "file": null,
      "function": "Error",
      "line": null,
      "method": null,
      "native": true
    }
  ],
  "stack": [
    "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'FILE.EXE'",
    " at Error (native)"
  ],
  "level": "error",
  "message": "uncaughtException: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'FILE.EXE'",
  "message": "uncaughtException: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'FILE.EXE'",
  "timestamp": "2017-07-03T09:09:29.645Z"
}
```

What I expect to happen is for the app to crash, restart and try again later. And if it can't process it x times, it goes in the dead letter queue.

The problem is, it just hangs and when I look at the task in ECS, it says "RUNNING".

So, it never restarts as it doesn't crash.

Is there any sort of configuration I need to do to get a Node Docker App to crash on an uncaught exception?

Comment: What does the code path to this error look like? Is it possible the code is forking processes and ECS is not seeing the exit codes from sibling processes?

Comment: possible... This particular failure is on an unzip of a file, so using `require('child_process').exec('unzip ...')` @AndyShinn

Comment: I would say that this is a code problem and not one of ECS or Docker. ECS is using Docker to run the container and Docker only knows about the parent process. If it forks additional processes and the code doesn't specifically handle the failure by exiting then it won't know about it and thus, nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry that was a lie, (facepalm). It's failing on `try {const file = fs.ReadStream(filepath); //redac} catch (e) {logger.FATAL(err, {backtrace: err.stack}, () => process.exit(1));}` @AndyShinn

Comment: But was that code forked from the initial process in `poll.js`? If so, Docker still won't see that exit code unless the code somehow propagates it back up through the tree.

Comment: Ok, admittedly this is sounding like new territory for me. I'm not explicitly doing any special forking, but could ReadStream be doing that? Reading the docs now... But I'm thinking I might have to add something like `file.on('error' () => process.exit())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148436/discussion-between-cameck-and-andy-shinn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the piece of code that was failing:

```
try {
  const file = fs.ReadStream(filepath);
  file.on('data', (d) => {
    task();
  }).on('end' () => {
    task();
  }
} catch (e) {
  logger.FATAL(err, {backtrace: err.stack}, () => process.exit(1));
}
```

Thanks to @AndyShinn, I added a listener for the error event:

```
.on('error', () => process.exit(1))
```

And all works now.

So, by adding an explicit error listener for a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) it is fixed.

Comment: So, it seems like a subprocess was created that Docker had no idea about and thus didn't crash. But I can't find any documentation that that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your script:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    process.exit(1)
})
```

Comment: So, that's interesting. [Node Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception), per this, printing the stack trace and exiting is the default action.

Comment: @cameck Maybe the Docker version overwrote this?

Comment: I don't think so, the more likely candidate is that docker doesn't know about a sub-process that failed.